# ParallelEnumerable.GroupBy: how lazy it is?

Tags: c#, web-crawler, task-parallel-library, linq-to-objects, plinq

MSDN says that `ParallelEnumerable.GroupBy` groups in parallel the elements of a sequence according to a specified key selector function.
So my question is: How lazy it is ?

It's clear that `ParallelQuery<IGrouping<,>>` is lazy. But what about `IGrouping<>` itself, is it lazy as well ?

So, if I do the following:

```
var entities = sites.AsParallel()
                         .Select(x => GetDataItemsFromWebsiteLazy(x))
                         .SelectMany(x => x)
                         .GroupBy(dataItem => dataItem.Url.Host)
                         .AsParallel()
                             .SelectMany(x => TransformToEntity(x));
```

Will `TransformToEntity` be called first time after all sites will fetch results?
Or as soon as first `GetDataItemsFromWebsiteLazy()` method will yield return an element?

The point of all that is to fire requests to different hosts in parallel.
Data processing goes as follows. For every website in a set:

1. Request website
2. Parse response and extract another site url
3. Request site by extracted url
4. Parse response and create entity from obtained data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `GroupBy` extension is, in fact, not lazy at all (or, more accurately, not *deferred* at all), as can be easily demonstrated with the following test program:

```
void Main()
{
    var source = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }.AsParallel();
    var groupEven = GetEvenNumbersUsingGroupBy(source);
    // foreach (int num in groupEven) { }
}

IEnumerable<int> GetEvenNumbersUsingGroupBy(IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Method called: GetEvenNumbersUsingGroupBy");
    var grouped = source.GroupBy(i => i % 2);
    return grouped.Where(g => g.Key == 0).Single();
}
```

This program outputs the following:

> Method called: GetEvenNumbersUsingGroupBy

Meaning that even though we never actually iterate the result of the `GetEvenNumbersUsingGroupBy` method, it still gets executed.

This is in contrast to a normal deferred enumerable using the `yield` statement, as in:

```
void Main()
{
    var yieldEven = GetEvenNumbersUsingYield(source);
    foreach (int num in yieldEven) { }
    foreach (int num in yieldEven) { }
}

IEnumerable<int> GetEvenNumbersUsingYield(IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Method called: GetEvenNumbersUsingYield");
    foreach (int i in source)
        if ((i % 2) == 0)   
            yield return i;
}
```

This prints the following:

> Method called: GetEvenNumbersUsingYield
>   Method called: GetEvenNumbersUsingYield

In other words, each time you iterate the results, they are re-evaluated, which is a typical characteristic of deferred evaluation (as opposed to straight-up lazy loading which caches the result after the first evaluation).

Note that this is the same whether you use `AsParallel` or not; it's a characteristic of the `GroupBy` extension (which by definition needs to build a hash table or other kind of lookup in order to store the individual groups) and wholly independent of concurrency.

It's easy to see why this is the case if you think about how you would *implement* a deferred grouping function; in order to iterate all of the elements of a single group, you would have to iterate the entire sequence to be sure that you've actually covered all of the elements of that group. So while it might *technically* be possible to defer this one-time iteration of the entire sequence, it's probably not worth it in most cases, since it's going to have the exact same memory and CPU characteristics as the eagerly-loaded version.

Comment: thank you Aaronaught, your reason is clear to me, and it's definitely an answer that I was looking for. But what about specific case when every iteration requires web request\response ? are you sure that in this case processing algorithm will not benefit from  parallel execution ?

Comment: one more point - I thought that ParallelEnumerable::GroupBy is implemented explicitly and contains different logic than the sequential version has ... otherwise how you can yield things in parallel and then wait for all methods to return ?

Comment: @ILICH: I never said that `ParallelEnumerable.GroupBy` has the same *implementation* as as `Enumerable.GroupBy`, just the same *limitations* as far as deferred evaluation is concerned; it still has to build the lookup. In response to your first comment, if you are executing web requests or any kind of slow I/O then `ParallelEnumerable` is not appropriate since it is designed for CPU-bound operations; you need to be using the async methods (e.g. `BeginGetResponse`) in order to take advantage of the asynchrony provided by those classes (typically based in I/O completion ports, not just threads).

Comment: i will definitely use it together with async way of doing web requests, but it's just the matter of memory resources consumption and emptying a thread pool. My primary concern is execution requests in parallel and it has nothing to do with async in my case if threadpool is big enough. So, i'm just curious, can my processing algorithm benefit from completely deferred execution ?

Comment: take attention to the TransformToEntity select many clause - it performs iteration in parallel over result of groupby. It means that it's not necessarily iterates one group and then goes to another. It could start yielding first elements from all groups simultaneously, in this case performance improves dramatically. What do you think ?

Comment: haha, do I really need second call of .AsParallel() there ? probably it's better to write simple console app as you did and experiment with it a bit ! thanks !

Comment: @ILICH: I've already stated clearly here that you're not getting completely deferred evaluation. The second `SelectMany` will be deferred but the `GroupBy` will not, which means you are essentially getting the worst of both worlds, immediate execution *and* repeated evaluation on every enumeration. You're getting absolutely no benefit here and async I/O is not meant to be combined with worker threads. Don't just assume that doing something in "parallel" is going to improve performance, unless and until you fully understand the performance characteristics of the non-parallel version.

Comment: The GroupBy is deferred, as all LINQ methods except those which make the IEnumerable query to run/execute. Already mentioned by you FOR statement is one of them. The Single method is another one. So to make your example clear - don't use it. This answer has nothing with proving deferring of the GroupBy method. Your first method returns a query (IEnumerable), but it's still a method and it's called from main. Thus you see the console text....

Comment: ...Your second method IS a query (will be converted to a query by a compiler). Thus it's will NOT run/execute util something will ask it to (FOR, Single, First, ToList, etc). To prove deferring use this: ...GroupBy(i => { Console.WriteLine("deferred"); return i % 2;})... don't forget to remove Single. And yep, it's mine -1

Comment: You are wrong. As a matter of fact GroupBy is executed deferred. In your example you finalize the deferred query by calling Single. Otherwise GroupBy returns a IGrouping which is a IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1):

The `GroupBy` operator, both in [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.groupby) and [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby), is implemented by using deferred execution. The query represented by this method is not executed until it is enumerated. But executing the query does not have the behavior that you want. The `GroupBy` yields groupings, and no grouping is yielded before the source sequence is fully enumerated. The [`IGrouping<TKey,TElement>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2) as a structure is internally just an immutable array with a `Key` property. It's a materialized collection, not a deferred enumerable. When the `GroupBy` yields a grouping, it contains all the elements of the source sequence that have the specific key. No other element is going to be added to it in the future.

Apparently what you want to achieve is what is known as "task parallelism". This means performing different operations on the same data, where these operations are running in parallel to each other. In contrast the "data parallelism" is to perform the same operation in parallel on different subsets of the data. The PLINQ library is designed to support data parallelism. The tool of choice for implementing task parallelism is the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library. If you really want to do it with PLINQ, [it's doable but tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62035864/design-help-for-parallel-processing-azure-blob-and-bulk-copy-to-sql-database-c/62041200#62041200). And you might still miss useful features like the backpressure, which is natively supported in TPL Dataflow with the [`BoundedCapacity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.boundedcapacity) option.