# Design help for parallel processing Azure blob and bulk copy to SQL database

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, azure-blob-storage

I have a requirement to fetch blob files from Azure storage, read through them, get the data and process it, and store it into a database. The number of data fetched from blob is high, i.e. around 40K records per file. There are 70 files like this in a folder.

This is how I designed it:

- I use `Parallel.Foreach` on list of blob files with max parallelism 4.
- In each loop, I fetch stream a blob (`OpenRead` method), read through it and fill a datatable. If the datatable size is 10000, I will call `SqlBulkCopy` and insert the data into the database.

In one folder of blob there are 70 files.

```
Parallel.Foreach {
    // Stream blob file
    // Create a datatable
    foreach item in file
    {
        AddToDatatable

        if(datatable > 5000)
        {
             BulkCopy to DB.
             Clear datatable
        } 
    }

    // Dispose datatable
}
```

Some observations I found is, when I increase the parallel count the time taken to process one file increase. Is it because I'm opening multiple blob stream in parallel? Also multiple parallel causes more data to be stored in memory at a time.

I would like to know 2 things:

1. I would like to try a different design where I can keep a single datatable and fill it from the parallel foreach. Then if it reaches 10K records, I should store in DB and clear. I don't know how to implement it.
2. If there's a better approach in terms of processing the files faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current approach is quite logical. It is not optimal though, because each parallel workflow is composed of heterogeneous jobs, that are not coordinated with the other workflows. For example it is entirely possible that at a given moment all four parallel workflows are fetching data from Azure, at another moment all four are constructing datatables from raw data, and another moment all four are waiting for a response from the database.

All these heterogeneous jobs have different characteristics. For example the interaction with the database may not be parallelizable, and sending 4 concurrent `SqlBulkCopy` commands to the database may be actually slower than sending them the one after the other. On the other hand creating datatables in memory is probably highly parallelizable, and fetching data from Azure may be benefited by parallelism only slightly (because the bottleneck could be the speed of your internet connection, and not the speed of the Azure servers). It is quite certain though that you could achieve a performance boost between 2x-3x by just making sure that at any given moment all heterogeneous jobs are in progress. This is called [task-parallelism](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data-parallelism-vs-task-parallelism), in contrast to the simpler data-parallelism (your current setup).

To achieve task-parallelism you need to create a pipeline, where the data are flowing from the one processing block to the next, until they reach the final block. In your case you probably need 3 blocks:

1. Download files from Azure and split them to raw records.
2. Parse the records and push the parsed data to datatables.
3. Send the datatables to the database for storage.

Sending single records from the first block to the second block may not be optimal, because the parallelism has overhead, and the more granular the workload the more overhead it creates. So ideally you would need to chunkify the workload, and batch the records to arrays before sending them to the next block. All this can be implemented with a great tool¹ that is designed for exactly this kind of job, the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library. It has blocks for transforming, batching, unbatching and whatnot. It is also very flexible and feature-rich regarding the options it offers. But since it has some learning curve, I have something more familiar to suggest as the infrastructure for the pipeline: the [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) library.

Any time you add the `AsParallel` operator to a query, a new processing block is started. To force the data to flow to the next block as fast as possible, the `WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)` operator is needed. For controlling the degree of parallelism there is the `WithDegreeOfParallelism`, and to keep them in the original order there is the `AsOrdered`. Lets combine all these in a single extension method for convenience, to avoid repeating them over and over again:

```
public static ParallelQuery<TSource> BeginPipelineBlock<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int degreeOfParallelism)
{
    return Partitioner
        .Create(source, EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering)
        .AsParallel()
        .AsOrdered()
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(degreeOfParallelism)
        .WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered);
}
```

The reason for the `Partitioner` configured with [`NoBuffering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.enumerablepartitioneroptions) is for ensuring that the PLINQ will enumerate the `source` in its natural order, one item at a time. Without it the PLINQ utilizes some fancy partitioning strategies, that are not suitable for this usage.

Now your pipeline can be constructed fluently like this:

```
files
    .BeginPipelineBlock(degreeOfParallelism: 2)
    .SelectMany(file => DownloadFileRecords(file))
    .Chunk(1000)
    .BeginPipelineBlock(degreeOfParallelism: 3)
    .Select(batch => CreateDataTable(batch))
    .BeginPipelineBlock(degreeOfParallelism: 1)
    .ForAll(dataTable => SaveDataTable(dataTable));
```

The [`Chunk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk) is a LINQ operator that splits the elements of a sequence into chunks:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource[]> Chunk<TSource> (
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int size);
```

---

**Important:** If you use the above technique to build the pipeline, you should avoid configuring two consecutive blocks with `degreeOfParallelism: 1`. This is because of how PLINQ works. This library does not depend only on background threads, but it also uses the current thread as a worker thread. So if two (or more) consecutive pipeline blocks are configured with `degreeOfParallelism: 1`, they will all attempt to execute their workload in the current thread, blocking each other, and defeating the whole purpose of task-parallelism.

This shows that this library is not intended to be used as a pipeline infrastructure, and using it as such imposes some limitations. So if it makes sense for your pipeline to have consecutive blocks with `degreeOfParallelism: 1`, the PLINQ becomes not a viable option, and you should look for alternatives. Like the aforementioned [TPL Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow) library.

---

**Update:** It is actually possible to link consecutive blocks having `degreeOfParallelism: 1`, without squeezing them into a single thread, by offloading the enumeration of the `source` to another thread. This way each block will run on a different thread. Below is an implementation of a `OffloadEnumeration` method, based on a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1):

```
/// <summary>
/// Offloads the enumeration of the source sequence to the ThreadPool.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<T> OffloadEnumeration<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, int boundedCapacity = 1)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    using BlockingCollection<T> buffer = new(boundedCapacity);
    Task reader = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try { foreach (T item in source) buffer.Add(item); }
        catch (InvalidOperationException) when (buffer.IsAddingCompleted) { } // Ignore
        finally { buffer.CompleteAdding(); }
    });

    try
    {
        foreach (T item in buffer.GetConsumingEnumerable()) yield return item;
        reader.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // Propagate possible source error
    }
    finally
    {
        // Prevent fire-and-forget
        if (!reader.IsCompleted) { buffer.CompleteAdding(); Task.WaitAny(reader); }
    }
}
```

This method should be invoked at the beginning of each block:

```
public static ParallelQuery<TSource> BeginPipelineBlock<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int degreeOfParallelism)
{
    source = OffloadEnumeration(source);
    return Partitioner
        .Create(source, EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering)
        .AsParallel()
        .AsOrdered()
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(degreeOfParallelism)
        .WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered);
}
```

This is really only useful when the previous block has `degreeOfParallelism: 1`, but calling it always shouldn't add much overhead (assuming that the workload of each block is fairly chunky).

---

**Note:** Another drawback of using the PLINQ library as a processing pipeline, is that its backpressure policy is not configurable. This means that if the consumer of the `ParallelQuery<T>` enumerates it very slowly, the pipeline will keep fetching data from the source `IEnumerable<T>`, and processing them in parallel, until its internal buffer reaches an arbitrary size. This threshold is experimentally found to be somewhere between 1,000 and 50,000 elements, depending on whether the `AsOrdered` operator is present. I can't see any public API that allows to configure the size of this buffer, which can be a big problem if each piece of data occupies a large chunk of memory.

¹ <sub>Currently (October 2023) I am no longer a proponent of the TPL Dataflow library. The components of this library have the annoying [by design](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29619) behavior to suppress `OperationCanceledException`s that might be thrown by the `action`, resulting in erroneously reporting successful `Completion` in this case. Even worse, I've realized that the linking functionality is [fundamentally broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603428/tpl-dataflow-exception-in-transform-block-with-bounded-capacity/69209696#69209696), with no hope to be fixed any time soon. The TPL Dataflow components are too loosely connected to each other. Finally it's remarkably difficult to extend. To write a custom block you have to implement weird interfaces, with sparse instructions for how to implement them.</sub>

Comment: This gave quite an insight to my approach and also to task parallelism. Thanks for the effort.  I have some doubts to clear. In this pipeline does it send the data batch by batch till the last block, until all the files are processed? What does the Buffer(1000) does?

Comment: My pleasure @Binil! Yes, the data are propagated from the one block to the other, processed and transformed along the way, until the last `ForAll` operation where no more data transformation occurs. The `Buffer(1000)` is a non-parallel operator that receives single records from the first block (notice the preceding `SelectMany` instead of `Select`), and buffers them in its internal buffer until they reach the number of 1000. When this happens it yields an array of 1000 elements, empties its buffer, and starts all over again. Obviously the last yielded array may have less than 1000 elements.