# Creating an IObservable<T> that returns properly a ton of data (asynchronously?)

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive

I am not all that familiar with `IObservable<T>`, but a package I am using forced it on me in a way.

I am expected to return an `IObservable<T>` on which at a later point Subscribe is called, and then the result of that gets disposed immediately after. And my intent is to fill it with data from a massive dataset. It reads line by line from text files, for GB's worth of data.

But I can't seem to find a good example of how I can make my hour long while loop, into an observable in a way that it doesn't expect all data to be read up front.
I see that there are some variants of `Observable.FromAsync`, but Tasks aren't my strong suit either, and can't seem to get that to work either.

The best I managed so far is below. Which compiles and runs, but does absolutely nothing. Never even calls the code inside the `Create` as far as I can tell.

```
public static IObservable<Data> GetHistoricalData(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return Observable.Create<Data>(async (subject, token) =>
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream stream = null;
            StreamReader sr = null;
            DateTime date = startDate;
            string path = string.Format("C:\\MYPATH\\{0}-{1}-{2}.csv", date.Year,
                date.Month.ToString("00"), date.Day.ToString("00"));
            while (date < endDate)
            {
                if (!File.Exists(path))
                {
                    date.AddDays(1);
                    continue;
                }
                stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Read);
                sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
                    Data d = ParseData(line);
                    subject.OnNext(d);
                }
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    sr.Close();
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                subject.OnError(ex);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An exception was thrown while trying to call" +
                    " OnError on the observable subject -- means you're not" +
                    " catching exceptions");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }).Publish();
}
```

I am not even sure if what I want to do is even technically possible, as I am not sure how the Observable pattern works. But due to the context it seems to expect a server connection feeding it a `DataStream` normally. So I assume it can be done. But only with the right combination of Observable creation methods.

If anyone has some good documentation to read up on that explains this in a starter friendly way, that would be nice as well.

As requested, how the method is called below, but it mostly goes into a blackbox library.

```
IObservable<Data> data = GetHistoricalData(
    new DateTime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    new DateTime(2021, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));

// Build charts from data
IObservable<(Data, Chart)> dataWithChart = data.GenerateCharts(TimeFrame);

// Generate signals from the charts
IObservable<(Signal, Chart)> signalsWithChart = dataWithChart.GenerateSignals(
    Symbol, strategy);

// We're interested in the signals only
IObservable<Signal> signals = signalsWithChart.SelectSignals();

// Show information from each signal
IDisposable subscription = signals.Subscribe(ShowSignal);
subscription.Dispose();
```

Comment: In my experience using `Observable.Create` is almost always the wrong way to go. It creates observables that can cause race conditions and you get stuck with thinking in procedural, rather than functional, terms.

Comment: Can you also include how the `GetHistoricalData` method is called? Is it used like that? `var subscription = GetHistoricalData(date1, date2); subscription.Dispose();`

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Added it as requested, but i didn't originally post it because i think it doesn't add much value as it goes through a black box 5 times over.

Comment: Hmm, so you say that neither of the methods `GenerateCharts`, `GenerateSignals`, `SelectSignals` and `ShowSignal` is under your control? You can't modify any of these methods? Do you have the source code of these methods at least?

Comment: If I go reverse engineering, yes. Otherwise, I can't really do much about them.

Comment: It might be useful to study the source code of these methods, in order to understand if the package does only filtering/projecting/combining of the data, or if it also does stuff that change the concurrency/scheduling of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should read ["Introduction to Rx"](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/00_Foreword.html), especially the section about hot and cold observables, and [publish and connect](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/14_HotAndColdObservables.html#PublishAndConnect).

There are several smaller issues with your code.
I made a simpler version of your code, and it worked after I removed the call to `.Publish()`. And I'm fairly certain you don't want that here.

`Publish` makes a wrapper that supports multiple observers. You can make it work for multiple observers by using `Publish()`, and then calling `Connect` once all observers are subscribed. But publishing works better for "hot" streams, like mouse/keyboard events, for example. Your data is only read once. Any observable that connects after you call `Connect` will not get the data that has already been read. If you need multiple subscribers like this, I would return `IConnectableObservable` instead of `IObservable`, so you can `Connect()` to it once all observers are subscribed.

As for your code:

- Keep it simple. Use `using` whenever you work with a stream, unless you know really well why you shouldn't.
- Calculate the path inside the loop. Use string interpolation instead of `string.Format()`.
- Call `subject.OnCompleted()` at the end.
- Re-assign the `date` variable. `DateTime` values in c# are immutable. `date.AddDays()` does not modify `date`, but returns a new `DateTime`.
- Use the FileMode you actually want. You don't want .Create if you don't intend to call the code if the file doesn't exist.

This works for me:

```
public IObservable<Data> GetHistoricalData(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return Observable.Create<Data>(async (subject, token) =>
    {
        var date = startDate;
        try
        {
            while (date < endDate)
            {
                string path = $@"C:\MYPATH\{date.Year}-{date.Month:00}-{date.Day:00}.csv";

                if (File.Exists(path))
                {
                    using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            var line = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                            {
                                var data = ParseData(line);
                                subject.OnNext(data);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                date = date.AddDays(1);
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            subject.OnError(e);
        }
        
        subject.OnCompleted();
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to exit the `while` after the `OnError`. You can't continue the loop after an error.

Comment: Well, at the very least, it is now working, and processing the method. It buggers out after like 100 lines read from the first file, but that is probably not entirely the fault of this code as is.

Thanks for pointing out the rookie mistakes, i was entirely not focused on that at the moment (i also forgot to add a day after EOF was hit as well)

I will read up a bit more in the links you provided and go from there. thanks again!

Comment: Of course i need to make sure my Main method keeps running until all file processing is done. Now it works fine.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity, this was botched while moving my testing code into SO.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your code is consumed by a package that misuses the `IObservable<T>` monad, by treating it as an `IEnumerable<T>`. When someone `Subscribe`s to an observable sequence and then immediately unsubscribes, they are only going to observe the notifications pushed synchronously during the subscription. Which is equivalent to enumerating synchronously an `IEnumerable<T>`. So my suggestion is to simplify your life by writing `IEnumerable<T>`-based code, and then pass the sequence to the package after converting it to observable with the [`ToObservable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229069(v=vs.103)) Rx operator:

```
public static IEnumerable<Data> GetHistoricalData(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    //...
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path))
    {
        yield return ParseData(line);
    }
    //...
}
```

Conversion from enumerable to observable:

```
IObservable<Data> data = GetHistoricalData(date1, date2).ToObservable();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this imply that i have to have the entire dataset in memory before i can make it observable? With a multi GB sized dataset this would be a prohibitive method.
Though i do agree this observable stuff felt kind of forced.

Comment: @Smileynator I don't think so. You read one line from the file at a time, you parse it and you `yield` the parsed `Data`. That data are then pushed to the observer provided by the package. The package does whatever it wants with them, and then the control is back to you, to read the next line from the file. Everything will happen while the package has called the `Subscribe` method. When the `Subscribe` returns, everything will be done. Disposing the `IDisposable` will be a no-op.

Comment: @Smileynator in case you want to parse the next piece of data while the package does its thing with the previous piece, in other words if you want to introduce parallelism, you could consider using the `OffloadEnumeration` method that I've posted near the bottom of in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62035864/design-help-for-parallel-processing-azure-blob-and-bulk-copy-to-sql-database-c/62041200#62041200) answer. You could use it like this: `IObservable<Data> data = GetHistoricalData(date1, date2).OffloadEnumeration().ToObservable();`

Answer (score -1):

Here you go. One nice query:

```
public static IObservable<Data> GetHistoricalData(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) =>
    from n in Observable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
    let d = startDate.AddDays(n)
    where d < endDate
    let path = $"C:\\MYPATH\\{d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}.csv"
    where File.Exists(path)
    from l in Observable.Using(
        () => File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
        s => Observable.Using(
            () => new StreamReader(s),
            sr => Observable.While(
                () => !sr.EndOfStream,
                Observable.Defer(
                    () => Observable.FromAsync(
                    () => sr.ReadLineAsync())))))
    select ParseData(l);
```