# C# parallel mapping iterator retaining order

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, enumerator

I have an `Enumerator<T>` as input, a mapping function that converts a `T` to an `S`, and I want to deliver an `Enumerator<S>` containing the results of the mapping. The mapping function is potentially expensive (for example, it might parse a 1Mb XML document) so I want to process multiple items in parallel; but I want the output `Enumerator<S>` to retain order. This means there will have to be some buffering; but I don't want to retain the whole sequence in memory.

I currently have this working using a `Parallel.ForEach()` and a `ChannelWriter/ChannelReader` pair: the callback in the `ForEach` applies the mapping function and writes the result to the `ChannelWriter`, and the result `Enumerator` reads the items using the `ChannelReader`. The only problem is that this doesn't retain order (mapped items are delivered in the order they become available, which is different from the input order).

I get the impression that there's a role here for an `OrderablePartitioner`, but I'm having great difficulty finding any usable information on how to use this class.

Comment: Instead of a pull model, why not use a _push model_ via _TPL Dataflow_?  It's also ideal for a mixture of I/O-bound or CPU-bound blocks.

Comment: We do in fact use a mixture of pull and push based pipelines, but this particular code has to sit in a pull pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably the [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) library. The [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.select) operator does the mapping, the [`AsOrdered`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asordered) ensures the preservation of order, and a couple of options regarding buffering ensures that the PLINQ buffers as little as possible:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Map<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TResult> mapping,
    int degreeOfParallelism)
{
    return Partitioner
        .Create(source, EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering)
        .AsParallel()
        .AsOrdered()
        .WithDegreeOfParallelism(degreeOfParallelism)
        .WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)
        .Select(mapping);
}
```

In case you wish to chain the `Map` method multiple times consecutively in a pattern of a pipeline, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62035864/design-help-for-parallel-processing-azure-blob-and-bulk-copy-to-sql-database-c/62041200#62041200) answer.